# Adding to dictionary records from data table

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ms-access, ado.net

I am new to the MVVM pattern.I have created  MVVM pattern where I have to fill the list to treeview control.I have view, view model and Model.I have populated data  in model through hard coding .But now I want to connect  my MS Access data table to list in the Model  instead of hard coded data.I have created DAL lier and connected my MS Access data table  as below:

```
        using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
namespace DAL2
{
    public class PersonalDAL
    {
       // static String _ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStr"].ConnectionString;
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\faisal\\Xerox2014\\wpf\\WPFHierarchy\\IconnectDB.accdb");

        public DataTable loademp( )
        {
            con.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from empTable", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);


            con.Close();
            return dt;
        }
    }

}
```

Here the loademp method will return the data table.
In model I am just trying to fill the list .the code where I have got stuck is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using DAL2;
using System.Data;

namespace DevLake.OrgChart.UI.Model
{
    class OrgChartManager
    {
        private static OrgChartManager self;

        //orgchart stored in dictionary
        private Dictionary<int, Node> list = new Dictionary<int, Node>();

        private OrgChartManager()
        {

           DataTable my_datatable = new DataTable();
        my_datatable = new PersonalDAL().loademp();
            int ColumnCount = my_datatable.Columns.Count;
            foreach (DataRow dr in my_datatable.Rows)
            {
                list.Add(dr);
               //******here I get stuck and throw syntax error on this line


            }


            //hard coded populate data
                // list.Add(1, new Node { Id = 1, FirstName = "Joe", LastName =                                                       "Smith", ParentId = 1 });
            //list.Add(2, new Node { Id = 2, FirstName = "Rich", LastName =    "Angel", ParentId = 1 });
                 //list.Add(3, new Node { Id = 3, FirstName = "Mary", LastName = "Peach", ParentId = 1 });
```

Here I am not able  fill the list it throw syntax error .Any body can help me how to fill my list with the data table data .my MS Access table look like this:

```
ID  FirstName   LastName    ParentId
1   Joe Smith   1
10  Grey    Peech   9
11  Manny   Travel  9
2   Rich    Angel   1
3   Mary    Peach   1
4   Mike    Door    2
5   Jimmy   Fond    2
6   Ann Brown   4
7   George  Farm    4
8   Able    Jump    4
9   Corn    Shaw    1
```

I am able to connect the data base and bring the data table to my model but filling the data table data in to list is where I got stuck..please help me friends

my node class:

```
    class Node
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public int ParentId { get; set; }

    }
}

    Drow donw item contro within the data contarol

  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/
```

https://www.codemag.com/Article/1407051/Python-for-C

Comment: How you do this depends upon the `Node` class. What does that look like?

Comment: my node class:    class Node
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public int ParentId { get; set; }

    }
}

Comment: There's lots of stuff here about WPF/MVVM that is really irrelevant.  The question should be trimmed down to just creating a Node instance from your DataRow instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        foreach (DataRow dr in my_datatable.Rows)
        {
            Node node = new Node
            {
                 Id = (int)dr["ID"]
                 FirstName = (string)dr["FirstName"],
                 LastName = (string)dr["LastName"],
                 ParentId = (int)dr["ParentId"]
            };
            list[node.Id] = node;
        }
```